# Sorting an array by alphabetical order before it is selected by UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, sorting, uipickerview

I am new to iphone development and need some guidance to do custom sorting of an array in iOS. I would like to sort the objects that appear in the UIPickerView. The objects that are passed to the UIPickerView are in an array.

When I print the array out, it looks like this:

```
    "<ObjectsInfo: 0x1c5249f0>",
    "<ObjectsInfo: 0x1c524940>",
    "<ObjectsInfo: 0x1c5248e0>",
    "<ObjectsInfo: 0x1c524890>",
    "<ObjectsInfo: 0x1c524840>",
    "<ObjectsInfo: 0x1c524a90>",
```

When i print out the first object's name:

```
    ObjectsInfo *object = [objectModelName objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",object.str_name);
```

It prints out: Alpha

The values given are examples. I would like to sort the array objectModelName in alphabetical order.

How do i do that?

I tried this:

```
[objectModelName sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

How do i do custom sorting based on the str_name so that it is in alphabetical order? Need some guidance... Really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [objectModelName sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(ObjectsInfo *firstObject, ObjectsInfo *secondObject) {
            return [firstObject.str_name compare:secondObject.str_name];
        }];
```

Comment: when i do that it says: "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *_strong' from 'NSArray *_strong'"....

Comment: After your code,i assign back sortedArray to objectModelName. it looks like this:NSArray *sortedArray = [objectModelName sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(ObjectsInfo *firstObject, ObjectsInfo *secondObject) {
            return [firstObject.str_name compare:secondObject.str_name];
        }];objectModelName = sortedArray;

Comment: Try using objectModelName = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray]; after this line.

Comment: that line converts an array to mutablearray version of it?

Comment: ya... thanks... out of curiosity? could i use mutablecopy? e.g arrModelName =[sortedArray mutableCopy];? works the same right?

Comment: Yes, you can use that. If you are not using ARC, you might have to release it yourself.

Comment: one more qn: you are using blocks in terms of functional paradigm? am i right to say that?

Comment: I am not sure you can call blocks that way. Yes, it is kind of.

Answer (score 3):

[objectModelName sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareItem:)];

In ObjectsInfo.h

```
  - (NSComparisonResult)compareItem:(ObjectsInfo *)anotherItem;
```

In ObjectsInfo.m

```
  - (NSComparisonResult)compareItem:(ObjectsInfo *)anotherItem{

    return [self.str_name compare:anotherItem.str_name options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

  }
```