# Sorting an array having dates

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray`, and I want to sort it by date, descending.
The date looks like:

Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You're getting downvotes because of one or more of the following: meaningless title (hi can you help me?), lack of research or evidence that you have tried anything (there are several sort-related methods in the documentation for nsmutablearray, and you haven't mentioned any of them) and this is probably a duplicate (asked and answered here before). Please read the FAQ for how to avoid this in the future.

Comment: Do you have NSDate objects in your array or it's just simple string?? And please read [FAQ] before putting your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array by alphabetical order before it is selected by UIPickerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265667/sorting-an-array-by-alphabetical-order-before-it-is-selected-by-uipickerview)

Comment: How did you mean it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only dates in array then it can be sort by:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
return [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Or using blocks

```
NSArray *reverseOrderUsingComparator = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: 
                                       ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                           return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                                       }];
```

EDIT:

As per discussion please check the code :

Assumimg you have a class having these properties :

```
//MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property(strong) NSString *title;
@property(strong) NSString *description;
@property(strong) NSDate *pubDate;

@end
```

---

```
//MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _title=[NSString new];
        _description=[NSString new];
        _pubDate=[NSDate new];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSComparisonResult)comparePubDate:(MyClass *)pd{
    return [_pubDate compare:[pd pubDate]];
}
@end
```

---

In your class where you have array of objects

In .h

```
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *myClassObjects;
```

In .m

```
-(NSDate *)dateInMyFormat:(NSString *)dateString{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];
    NSDate *myDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    return myDate;    
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    MyClass *obj1=[MyClass new];
    [obj1 setTitle:@"obj1 title"];
    [obj1 setDescription:@"obj1 description"];
    [obj1 setPubDate:[self dateInMyFormat:@"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100"]];

    MyClass *obj2=[MyClass new];
    [obj2 setTitle:@"obj2 title"];
    [obj2 setDescription:@"obj2 description"];
    [obj2 setPubDate:[self dateInMyFormat:@"Fri, 08 jan 2012 08:40:33 +0100"]];

    MyClass *obj3=[MyClass new];
    [obj3 setTitle:@"obj3 title"];
    [obj3 setDescription:@"obj3 description"];
    [obj3 setPubDate:[self dateInMyFormat:@"Fri, 08 jan 2012 06:40:33 +0100"]];

    MyClass *obj4=[MyClass new];
    [obj4 setTitle:@"obj4 title"];
    [obj4 setDescription:@"obj4 description"];
    [obj4 setPubDate:[self dateInMyFormat:@"Fri, 01 Jan 2012 08:40:33 +0100"]];

    [_myClassObjects addObject:obj1];
    [_myClassObjects addObject:obj2];
    [_myClassObjects addObject:obj3];
    [_myClassObjects addObject:obj4];

    for (MyClass *object in _myClassObjects) {
        NSLog(@"Title:%@, %@, %@",object.title, object.description, object.pubDate);
    }

    //for sorting
    NSArray *sortedArray=[_myClassObjects sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(comparePubDate:)];
    _myClassObjects=(NSMutableArray *)sortedArray;

    NSLog(@"After sorting");
    for (MyClass *object in _myClassObjects) {
        NSLog(@"Title:%@, %@, %@",object.title, object.description, object.pubDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another question:)

Can you help me in this too?:)

I want to open an image with Safari, when I click on the image. The 
image is visualized by its URL.

Thanks for the answers!:)

Comment: but kindly accped this answer if it helped.

Comment: It will turn out tomorrow, in my workplace:). I will text you about the result:), but till then, can u answer for this question too?:)
thx for everything

Comment: I did not like to wait for a day, these are tested codes. And I would like to say you to post that question in SO. You can get many good answers, or atleast one, who knows it.

Comment: `I want to open an image with Safari, when I click on the image.` From  where will you click the image? Finder or some other application ?

Comment: When a Run my application, in a Scroll View.

Comment: you can try `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:yourURL];` yourURL should contain the image path. This i am not sure, will tell you tomorrow :)

Comment: But no vote and acceptance yet :(

Comment: The array contains title, description, pubDate. But I want to sort it by only pubDate. Is this really the good code for that?

Comment: array contains all three? or that array contains some object which has these three?

Comment: please send me your code vaidya.anoop@gmail.com I will check it and revert you soon

Comment: Yes, it contains some object with that three properties.

Comment: what happened? you accepted and roll backed?

Comment: Please give me the exact code according to this, and after it I accept your answer :):
it contains some object with that three properties.

Comment: show me full code what u have

Comment: Kindly check this one... and this one is working